# Inserting into 2 tables with foreign key in them into SQL Server with C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'd like to know the query of C# where I want to insert 2 tables with foreign key in them. The current code that I use:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(WindowsFormsApp1.Properties.Resources.connection.ToString());
con.Open();

SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("Begin TRANSACTION INSERT INTO daftar_buku values('"+Code.Text+"','"+Judul.Text+"','"+Kategori.Text+"','"+Nomor.Text+"') insert into stock_buku(nama_buku, stok_buku) values ((select judul_buku from daftar_buku where judul_buku ='"+Judul.Text+"'),'"+Stock.Text+"') COMMIT ",con);

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select judul_buku from daftar_buku where judul_buku = '"+Judul.Text+"'",con);

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);

if (dt.Rows.ToString() == Judul.Text)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Data Added!");
    this.Hide();
    Refresh();
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Failed To add Book!","Information");
}
```

But that code does not work...

Please help me

Comment: **1)** Do you get an error? **2)** Tell us which columns are the foreign keys-tell us more about your table structure.

Comment: its the "judul_buku" and "nama_buku" from tables daftar_buku and stock_buku

Comment: I would suggest you do a few thing, `1st read what Sql Injection is` `2nd create a stored procedure for you inserts and learn proper Transact SQL` `3rd read about how to construct parameterized querys` when showing Sql Exceptions use a `try{}catch{}` and the correct Exception class for the Datsabase you are using, and  show the message for the correct execption.Message